# Эпитеты к слову гавань

Tags: поэзия

Подберите, пожалуйста, несколько эпитетов к слову гавань (или порт). Заранее благодарю.

Comment: @roza, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Гавань может быть мелкой, глубокой, защищенной, плохой, неудобной, иностранной, чужой, своей, Василеостровской, местом жительства, далекой, близкой, новой, старой, прибрежной, морской, воздушной, речной, озерной.
Этимология Гавани, это слово ХОВАТЬ-прятать. ХОВАН.
спрятался в гавани -  смысловая тавтология.

Answer (score 1):

Есть своеобразные эпитеты в китайских географических названиях. Сянган (=Гонконг) - "ароматная гавань" (видимо, связано с перевозкой пряностей и чая). Город Ляньюньган - "гавань, соединённая с облаками", туманная.

Comment: А вы на корни это поделите, для полного кайфа, я лично иероглифы воспринимаю чисто по произношению, увидел слово хан, и вспомнил про ханов. Вы б это по отдельности, каждый.

Answer (score 1):

Есть своеобразные эпитеты в китайских географических названиях. Сянган (=Гонконг) - "ароматная гавань" (видимо, связано с перевозкой пряностей и чая). Город Ляньюньган - "гавань, соединённая с облаками", туманная.